# Invalidate access token or shorten access token for development tests Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am trying to see if my backend server that uses https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token works correctly to refresh expired tokens. However, right now, I have to wait for 1h before the current access token expires, making development slow. Is there a way to invalidate or shorten the access token for development purposes?